# How to Dynamically Display a Notification in Main UI from a Shiny Module?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny to create a web application and am encountering an issue related to managing notifications from a Shiny module. My aim is to dynamically display a notification in the main UI of my app, based on an action or value originating from a Shiny module, but am finding it challenging to make this functional smoothly.

Below is a simplified excerpt of my code:

```
library(shiny)

notifUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
  actionButton(ns("show_notif"), "Show Notification")
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  notifUI("notifModule"),
  uiOutput("notification")
)

notifServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$show_notif, {
    output$notification <- renderUI({
      # Example code to display the notification
      tags$div(
        id = "notif_div",
        class = "alert alert-warning",
        "This is a notification message."
      )
    })
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(notifServer, "notifModule")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I dynamically pass a message from the module to the main server to be displayed as a notification?

Is there a method or specific package that would facilitate managing notifications in this configuration with Shiny modules?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your module server is not set up correctly.  It does not call `moduleServer`.  See [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/) for more information.  Your module server needs to return a `reactive`.  Then simply monitor that return value in your main server.

Comment: If `output$notification` is in the server module, then `uiOutput("notification")` must be in the UI module (with the `ns`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full solution based on my comment above.  It is simpler than OP's because it does not require additional parameters to be passed to the module server, so communication is only from module to main app, not in both directions.

```
testUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("send"), "Send notification")
}

testServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      rv <- reactiveValues(message = NA)
      
      observeEvent(input$send, {
        rv$message <- paste0("Your random number is ", runif(1))
      })
      
      reactive({ rv$message })
    }
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  testUI("test"),
  textOutput("moduleMessage")
)

# Main app server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  msg <- testServer("test")
  
  output$moduleMessage <- renderText({
    req(msg())
    
    msg()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution, thanks to a nudge in the right direction from Limey!

Here’s the working solution I’ve come up with:

```
library(shiny)

# Module UI
notifUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("show_notif"), "Show Notification")
  )
}

# Module Server
notifServer <- function(input, output, session, notifMessage) {
  observeEvent(input$show_notif, {
    notifMessage("This is a notification message from the module.")
  })
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("notification"),
  notifUI("notifModule")
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive value to store the notification message
  notifMessage <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  # Call module with notifMessage as a parameter
  callModule(notifServer, "notifModule", notifMessage)

  # Observe notifMessage and if changed, render the notification UI
  output$notification <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(notifMessage())) {
      tags$div(
        id = "notif_div",
        class = "alert alert-warning",
        notifMessage()
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This method allows the module to set a notification message, which is then observed by the main server function, triggering the UI to update with the new notification message when a button inside the module UI is clicked.

Big thanks again to Limey for pointing me in the right direction, and I hope this might help others facing a similar issue in the future!