# Namespacing in InsertUI using modules

Tags: r, shiny, namespaces

i have problems retreiving the inputs of an Rshiny UI which was generated by InsertUI. I assume that the problem is somewhere in the Namespacing but i'm not able to solve.

In the following minimal example i tried to produce a minimal example and print one of the inputs, but i do not get anything else than NULL.

Thanks in Advance!
Roman

```
ActionButtonUI <- function(id, Label, Width = "100%") {
  shiny::actionButton(
    inputId = shiny::NS(id, "ActionInput"),
    label = Label,
    width = Width
  )
}

ActionButtonServer <- function(id) {
  shiny::moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ActionInput = shiny::reactive({
      shiny::req(input[["ActionInput"]])
    })
    
    ActionInput
  })
}

Produce_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  shiny::tagList(
    shiny::numericInput(
      inputId = ns("NumericValue1"),
      label = "Value",
      value = rnorm(1),
      min = 0,
      width = "100%"
    ),
    shiny::numericInput(
      inputId = ns("NumericValue2"),
      label = "Value",
      value = rnorm(1),
      min = 0,
      width = "100%"
    )
  )
  
}

Produce_UIServer <- function(id, actionbuttonAdd) {
  stopifnot(
    shiny::is.reactive(actionbuttonAdd)
  )
  shiny::moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    dynamicUI_counter <- shiny::reactiveVal(0)
    
    values <- reactiveValues(inputs = list())
    
    observeEvent(actionbuttonAdd(), {
      new_id <- paste0("numericInput_", dynamicUI_counter())
      
      values$inputs[[new_id]] <- Produce_UI(new_id)
      
      dynamicUI_counter(dynamicUI_counter() + 1)
      
      shiny::insertUI(
        selector = "#dynamicInput",
        ui = values$inputs[[new_id]]
      )
      #print(input)
      print(paste("Initial value for", new_id, ":", input[[paste0(new_id,"-NumericValue1")]]))
    })
    output[["dynamicInput"]] <- renderUI({
      do.call(tagList, values$inputs)
    })
  })
}


library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  ActionButtonUI("addBtn", "Add UI", Width = "49%"),
  uiOutput("dynamicInput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  AddUI <- ActionButtonServer("addBtn")
  Produce_UIServer("dynamicInput", actionbuttonAdd = AddUI)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: i'm not able to retreive the inputs of the dynamic UIs. Within this example i tried to print them using "input[[paste0(new_id,"-NumericValue1")]]" but they are always NULL, so not defined.

Comment: I find your architecture quite confusing so could be wrong, but I don't think that you have created the input where you have your current `print` statement. If you add a `renderText` / `textOutput` combo to your main server and UI then you can access e.g. `input$\`numericInput_0-NumericValue1\`` just fine. Note that the `\`` are required to stop the `-` being treated as minus.

Comment: Better yet, get your module server to return a value to the main server.  Monitor the return value instead and you don't have to worry about handling the `-`s in the namespaced input ID.  And it fit's better with the design pattern of modules, IMHO.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271095/how-to-dynamically-display-a-notification-in-main-ui-from-a-shiny-module/77271355#77271355) for an example of what I mean.